# Transparent proxy between docker containers via iptables

Tags: iptables, squid

I am trying to achieve http transparent proxy between 2 docker container.

I installed squid proxy. Let's call it **SQUID**, Also there is another container let's call it **APP**

I want that every http connection which requested from APP will be over SQUID container

Expected data flow  is APP ---> SQUID ---> http://example.com --> SQUID --> APP --> SUCCESS

By using tcpdump, I can proof that I did all necessary configuration correct and I am able to see page with curl command if I use -x

## Proof squid is working via -x

`curl  -x SQUID_IP:3128 -L http://www.example.com`

This curl command gives correct output.

`tcpdump -i any host www.example.com`

All communication between `SQUID_IP` and `EXAMPLECOM_IP`.

```
14:02:04.213608 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [S], seq 2965828629, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2305017503 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:02:04.213608 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [S], seq 2965828629, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2305017503 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:02:04.213634 IP $LINUX_NAME.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [S], seq 2965828629, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2305017503 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:02:04.335400 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $LINUX_NAME.48808: Flags [S.], seq 1004826113, ack 2965828630, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
14:02:04.335454 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $SQUID_IP.48808: Flags [S.], seq 1004826113, ack 2965828630, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
14:02:04.335465 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $SQUID_IP.48808: Flags [S.], seq 1004826113, ack 2965828630, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
14:02:04.335595 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64240, length 0
14:02:04.335595 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64240, length 0
14:02:04.335627 IP $LINUX_NAME.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64240, length 0
14:02:04.336027 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [P.], seq 1:200, ack 1, win 64240, length 199: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
14:02:04.464797 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $LINUX_NAME.48808: Flags [P.], seq 1:1421, ack 200, win 65535, length 1420: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
14:02:04.464871 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $SQUID_IP.48808: Flags [P.], seq 1:1421, ack 200, win 65535, length 1420: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
14:02:04.464888 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $SQUID_IP.48808: Flags [P.], seq 1:1421, ack 200, win 65535, length 1420: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
14:02:04.465051 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1421, win 63900, length 0
14:02:04.465051 IP $SQUID_IP.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1421, win 63900, length 0
14:02:04.465109 IP $LINUX_NAME.48808 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http: Flags [.], ack 1421, win 63900, length 0
14:02:04.465879 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP..http > $LINUX_NAME.48808: Flags [P.], seq 1421:1614, ack 200, win 65535, length 193: HTTP
```

### squid access log

```
1581166924.466    253 $APP_IP TCP_MISS/200 1751 GET http://www.example.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/$EXAMPLECOM_IP text/html
```

## Transparent proxy part

I want create same behaviour without -x or enviroment variable.

### Iptables rule which I wrote in the virtual machine

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -s $APP_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $PROXY_IP:3128
```

PS: Docker writes some rules at the beginning so I am always writing my iptables rules to the top.

## Failures

### Curl command without -X

`curl http://www.example.com/`

### tcpdump output that shows my APP_IP reach the $EXAMPLECOM_IP

`tcpdump -i any host www.example.com`

That is weird tcpdump shows communication between `APP_IP` and `EXAMPLECOM_IP`.

```
14:10:27.069971 IP $APP_IP.36286 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http: Flags [S], seq 2733675015, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3465975630 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:10:27.070010 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http > $APP_IP.36286: Flags [S.], seq 121743720, ack 2733675016, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3186379669 ecr 3465975630,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:10:27.070019 IP $APP_IP.36286 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3465975630 ecr 3186379669], length 0
14:10:27.070145 IP $APP_IP.36286 > $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:80, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3465975630 ecr 3186379669], length 79: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
14:10:27.070159 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http > $APP_IP.36286: Flags [.], ack 80, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3186379669 ecr 3465975630], length 0
14:10:27.070297 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http > $APP_IP.36286: Flags [P.], seq 1:3887, ack 80, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3186379669 ecr 3465975630], length 3886: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
14:10:27.070348 IP $EXAMPLECOM_IP.http > $APP_IP.36286: Flags [F.], seq 3887, ack 80, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3186379669 ecr 3465975630], length 0
```

### Squid log and error

```
1581168827.687      0 $APP_IP NONE/400 3886 GET / - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

```
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="/">/</a></p>
```

This is proof that my iptables rule route trafic but ?

## Question

What should be correct iptables between `SQUID` and `APP` to make it behave like transparent proxy.

**INFO NOTE**

There is not any additional iptables rule which I wrote all is here

```
iptables  -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N NO_PROXY
-A PREROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:3128
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
iptables  -t filter -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

```
export SQUID_IP=172.17.0.3
export APP_IP=172.17.0.2
```